# keydown event listener doesn't reliably work with 4+ keys

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

steps to reproduce:

1. open your chrome console
2. add this code `document.addEventListener('keydown',({key})=>{console.log(key)})`
3. press q, keep q pressed and press w, keep it pressed, same for e,r, and t.

In my case q,w,e, and r are all being console logged (multiple times while being pressed), however, as soon as I reach 't' (meaning I simultaneously press q-w-e-r-t) nothing is being console logged anymore.

This happens for me on chrome on a dell xps 15 9570.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent this? I'd like my last pressed key always to be shown, no matter how many other keys are pressed.

Comment: It works in my browser (Chrome)

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=nkro